# All combinations of list elements in certain order

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list as follows:

```
((0,n1,n2,...,nX),(0,n1,n2,...,nY),(1,n1,n2,...,nZ),(2,n1,n2,...,nR),(2,n1,n2,...,nS))
```

I would like to return all possible combinations of list elements in such way:

```
(0,n1,n2,...,nX),(1,n1,n2,...,nZ),(2,n1,n2,...,nR)
(0,n1,n2,...,nY),(1,n1,n2,...,nZ),(2,n1,n2,...,nR)
(0,n1,n2,...,nX),(1,n1,n2,...,nZ),(2,n1,n2,...,nS)
(0,n1,n2,...,nY),(1,n1,n2,...,nZ),(2,n1,n2,...,nS)
```

So, I have understood and worked out that I need to iterate through elements and check first item of the list element to group elements by first item.

It could let me to do maybe a for loop? and try to manualy create all combinations?

However I wonder if there is any better approach?

I need to keep in mind that the elements must be in order ascending by first item of the elements --> 0, 1, 2

EDIT:

This is my list in other words:

```
((0,A), (0,B), (1,C), (2,D),(2,E))
```

how to return as follows:

```
(0,A),(1,C),(2,D)
(0,B),(1,C),(2,D)
(0,A),(1,C),(2,E)
(0,B),(1,C),(2,E)
```

?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You want combinations of 3 elements? Are the tuples immutable? So does `(0,n1,n2,...,nX)` stay the same all the time? Is it just one element? Then just write it in a simpler form, say `A`.

Comment: there is a list which elements are lists (let's call them sublists). each sublist's first element is kind of ID. some sublists may have the same ID and some of them may be the only sublist with specific ID e.g. you can have few sublists with ID = 2 and e.g. just one sublist with ID = 5. I want to return all possible combination in such way that I pick a single sublist from the sublists with same ID and put in into combination returned but next time I skip that picked sublist and just take next available sublist from that sublists with same ID range ... does it make it clearer?

Comment: check example provided...you can see that returned combinations have single elements with unique first item e.g. there are no two items in each combination that have value 0 as first item of the element.

Comment: Yes it is clearer now. There is an easy way to do this, if you change your data structure a bit, and group all "sublists" with the same "ID" in separate lists.

Comment: Good point and this is what I thought but I have two challenges: how to group them in separate lists ... and how to create the possible combinations of these lists and keep an order so I do not have element from list 2 before element from list 1 ?

Comment: A bit of a naming nitpick: What you have written down are python tuples, not lists (lists are written within braces [ ]). Also an ID is usually a **unique** identifier, so I would not call the first element of the list an ID.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Any clue on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes easier if you change your data structures a bit. More specifically, just group all elements with the same "ID" in the same list.

For your example you have 3 lists:

```
a = [(0,n1,n2,...,nX),(0,n1,n2,...,nY)]
b = [(1,n1,n2,...,nZ)]
c = [(2,n1,n2,...,nR),(2,n1,n2,...,nS)]
```

Let me know if you have trouble separating the lists out like this, and I'll amend my answer.

Then you can use the itertools.product function to get all the combinations that you want.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.product(a, b, c):
    print i
```

Or if you want to see all the combinations as a list you can simply do:

```
list(itertools.product(a, b, c))
```

Similarly, you can use `tuple()` or `set()` if you want to see all the combinations as a tuple or a set.

EDIT:
If you to not have your elements already grouped together, and instead you have a flattened list(or tuple) of tuples you can create a list that groups tuples according to their "ID" (i.e., the first value of the simple tuples). Here's a function to do it. I assume there is no order in how the tuples are initially given (otherwise we can probably make this grouping more efficient)

```
def groupList(flatlist):
    tempdict = {}
    for element in flatlist:
        id = element[0]
        if id in tempdict:
            tempdict[id].append(element)
        else:
            tempdict[id] = [element]
    return list(tempdict.values())
```

Now you can used this "grouped" list to get all the combinations. Let's assume that you initial list is l, then you can do:

```
list(itertools.product(*groupList(l)))
```

**Notice the `*` when passing the argument**. This tells python to use the elements of this list as separate arguments to the function.

Example Input:

> l = ((0, 10), (0, 20), (1, 30), (2, 40), (2, 50))

Example Output:

> [((0, 10), (1, 30), (2, 40)), ((0, 10), (1, 30), (2, 50)), ((0, 20),
>   (1, 30), (2, 40)), ((0, 20), (1, 30), (2, 50))]

Comment: hey, thank you for your help. itertools helps a lot. how to break the list into few lists when you do not know how many sub lists you will get?

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope this answers your question fully.

Comment: it almost does the job...It return lists with elements not in the right order: e.g. id 1 is indexed 0, id 0 is indexed 1 id 2 is indexed 2. is it because dictionaries are unsorted by nature?

Comment: @user7583612 yes dictionaries are unsorted, but you can force a sorting when you are making the grouped list. Instead of returning `tempdic.values()` you can make the list as you like.

Comment: It seems strange though that it flips the indexes in your example (even though dict are unsorted). In my simple example above order is maintained.